# Draw a low resolution circle

Tags: java, graphics, fractals

I'm really stuck and out of ideas regarding this, I'm supposed to paint a circle, which goes fine. But it's going to be able to be painted in different resolutions, and I'm getting nowhere, please help! The code I show you here is not trying to work with differnet resolutions, but I have no ideas left on what to do.

I'll put up the class I'm having trouble with, and then I'll put up the rest of the program. Also a quick note, the program will later on be used for Mandlebrot sets.

The problem is, the circle works fine with High resolution, but once I try to decrease it, I get weird line patterns, like it only paints certain lines, and then paint lines it isn't supposed to, I'm suspecting the problem is the method `render()`. I also suspect the problem more specifically are the for-loops, or the index of my vectors. If I'm unclear in my explanation please tell me.

The RESOLUTION_VERY_HIGH to RESOLUTION_VERY_LOW have values 2048, 1024, ..., 128.

```
package mandelbrot;
import java.awt.Color;

import se.lth.cs.ptdc.fractal.MandelbrotGUI;

public class Generator {
    public Generator() {

    }

    public void render(MandelbrotGUI w) {
        w.disableInput();
        int resolution = 1;

         switch (w.getResolution()) {
            case MandelbrotGUI.RESOLUTION_VERY_HIGH:
             resolution = 1;
             break;
            case MandelbrotGUI.RESOLUTION_HIGH:
              resolution = 3;
              break;
            case MandelbrotGUI.RESOLUTION_MEDIUM:
              resolution = 5;
              break;
            case MandelbrotGUI.RESOLUTION_LOW:
              resolution = 7;
              break;
            case MandelbrotGUI.RESOLUTION_VERY_LOW:
              resolution = 9;
              break;
            }

        Complex complex[][] = mesh(w.getMinimumReal(), w.getMaximumReal(), w.getMinimumImag(),
                w.getMaximumImag(), w.getWidth(), w.getHeight());

        Color[][] picture = new Color[w.getHeight()][w.getWidth()];

        for (int i = 0; i<w.getHeight(); i+=resolution) {
            for (int j = 0; j<w.getWidth(); j+=resolution) {
                if ((complex[i][j]).getAbs()>1) {
                    picture[i][j] = Color.WHITE;
                }
                else {
                    picture[i][j] = Color.BLUE;
                }
            }
        }

        w.putData(picture, 1, 1);
        w.enableInput();
    }

    private Complex[][] mesh(double minReal, double maxReal, double minImaginary,
                                double maxImaginary, int width, int height) {

        Complex[][] matrice = new Complex[height][width];
        for (int i = 0; i<height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<width; j++) {
                matrice[i][j] = new Complex((minReal + ((maxReal-minReal)/width)*j),
                                            ((maxImaginary - (((maxImaginary - minImaginary)/height)*i))));

            }
        }
        return matrice;
    }
}
```

I doubt you need them, but here are the other classes;

My main;

```
package mandelbrot;
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.fractal.MandelbrotGUI;

public class Mandelbrot {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MandelbrotGUI w = new MandelbrotGUI();
        Generator generator = new Generator();
        boolean zoomValue = false;

        while (true) {
            switch(w.getCommand()) {

                case MandelbrotGUI.QUIT: System.exit(0);
                break;

                case MandelbrotGUI.RENDER:
                    generator.render(w);
                break;

                case MandelbrotGUI.RESET:
                w.clearPlane();
                w.resetPlane();
                zoomValue = false;
                break;

                case MandelbrotGUI.ZOOM:
                    if (zoomValue) {
                            w.clearPlane();
                            generator.render(w);
                            break;
                    }
                    else {break;}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Complex class I wrote;

```
package mandelbrot;

public class Complex {
    double real;
    double imaginary;

    public Complex (double real, double imaginary) {
        this.real = real;
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }

    double getReal() {
        return real;
    }
    double getImaginary() {
        return imaginary;
    }

    double getAbs() {
        return Math.hypot(real, imaginary);
    }

    void add(Complex c) {
        real += c.getReal();
        imaginary += c.getImaginary();
    }

    void multiply(Complex c) {
        real = (real*c.getReal()) - (imaginary*c.getImaginary());
        imaginary = (real*c.getImaginary()) + (imaginary*c.getReal());
    }
}
```

The specifications for the GUI you can find here; http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs//Education/EDA016/javadoc/cs_eda016_doc/

Thanks for any help, very much appreciated! :)

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a link to the source for the GUI class would you?  Not required but makes debugging easier if you can see exactly what your talking about and while I could reproduce from the spec, thats a lot of typing. :)

Comment: What do circles and Mandelbrot fractals have in common? If I have to draw a circle, I'd use sine and cosine functions, which yields a _true_ circle.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your code correctly and the operation of the GUI class.  There are two things you need to do.

1)  When in a resolution other than VERY_HIGH, you only set the color for every `resolution` points.  This may work but only if you change the size of the pixel you are painting with.  Without the GUI class, there is not enough information to say.  I get the feeling though that the if statement `if ((complex[i][j]).getAbs()>1` should read `if ((complex[i][j]).getAbs()>resolution` and the increment for i and j should be 1.  Again, without the GUI class, I can't say.

2)  To change the size of the pizel, all you should need to change is the `w.putData(picture,1,1);` command to read `w.putData(picture,resolution,resolution);`.

If this is incorrect, a link to the GUI source or adding pictures of the results you are currently getting will help.

Comment: Well, I wish I had access to the GUI source, but I only got the specifications, so it's about the same information that I got. I'll try to implement your thoughts in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I seem to have solved the problem, the method render is supposed to look like this;

```
public void render(MandelbrotGUI w) {
    w.disableInput();
    int resolution = 1;

     switch (w.getResolution()) {
        case MandelbrotGUI.RESOLUTION_VERY_HIGH:
         resolution = 1;
         break;
        case MandelbrotGUI.RESOLUTION_HIGH:
          resolution = 3;
          break;
        case MandelbrotGUI.RESOLUTION_MEDIUM:
          resolution = 5;
          break;
        case MandelbrotGUI.RESOLUTION_LOW:
          resolution = 7;
          break;
        case MandelbrotGUI.RESOLUTION_VERY_LOW:
          resolution = 9;
          break;
        }

    Complex complex[][] = mesh(w.getMinimumReal(), w.getMaximumReal(), w.getMinimumImag(),
            w.getMaximumImag(), w.getWidth(), w.getHeight());

    Color[][] picture = new Color[w.getHeight()/resolution + 1][w.getWidth()/resolution + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i<w.getHeight(); i+=resolution) {
        for (int j = 0; j<w.getWidth(); j+=resolution) {
            if ((complex[i][j]).getAbs()>1) {
                picture[i/resolution][j/resolution] = Color.WHITE;
            }
            else {
                picture[i/resolution][j/resolution] = Color.BLUE;
            }
        }
    }

    w.putData(picture, resolution, resolution);
    w.enableInput();
}
```

The increment was j+=resolution and i+=resolution, I also put the index of Color[][] to `w.getHeight/resolution + 1`, and `w.getWidth/resolution + 1`.

The explanation being that I only compare every "resolution" row (eg, every third row for resolution 3), and every "resolution" pixel on that row. Thus I need only `w.getWidth/resolution + 1` elements (and the same for w.getHeight).

Then I took `picture[i/resolution][j/resolution]`, I think the problem before was that I saved too many elements, and then when the pixelsize was increased, I had too many pixels.

Also, `w.putData(picture, resolution, resolution);`, which meant I expanded the pixelsize, and so the resolution was lower.

Thanks for all the trouble the people here went throught to help me.